# VBA runtime error 6 overflow - why is this happening?

Tags: excel, runtime-error, overflow, vba

In my answer to the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093497/finding-number-of-coprime-tuples-from-1-to-n/2094773#2094773 on Math SE, I am currently getting a runtime error on the line:

```
P=599*601
```

Error message is runtime error 6 overflow

P is defined as a Public variable of type double. I also have used p in my "modulo" function, defined as a double.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to correct it?

I have found a workaround:  If I change the stated line to have instead:

```
P=359999
```

Then the error does not occur. Hence why does the line P=599*601 give an error?

Comment: `P` is Double ? why ? in your case you should have it `As Long`, read more about data types here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx

Comment: So I need to change both data types to long for p? - ie in "Public P as Double" and in the modulo function "p as double" lines?

Comment: Question updated please review

Answer (score 0):

After research, I found that this quirk can be solved via the following code:

```
Dim Prime1 as Long
Dim Prime2 as Long
Public P as Long
...
P=Prime1 * Prime2
```

Cause of the problem is likely due to assignment of integer type to p due to numbers when multiplied being integers.

Comment: The cause is due to both `599` and `601` being integers, so a calculation of `Integer * Integer` tries to give an `Integer` result, and overflows.  As long as one of the two numbers is a `Long` (e.g. `P = 599& * 601`, or `P = 599 * 601&`, or `P = CLng(599) * 601`, etc) then the calculation would work.  After the calculation is finished, the result is placed in `P`, so at no time is `P` treated as `Integer`, just the intermediate calculation.